# Android:Creating helper class for onActivityResult() and calling it from another class

Tags: android-layout, android-activity

I need to create a helper class that does not extend Activity. This code is for loading from camera and from gallery based on RESULT.

I am not understanding how to call the class from the other class by using context (since it does not extend activity)
Please could you guys help me out?

below is the code i need to extract and call it in another class using context.

```
  enter code here
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.default_image);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            Log.i(TAG, "destination= " + destination);
            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
```

i created a new class named :ActivityResultHelper but encountering problem at findViewById
activity result helper

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * 
 */
public class ActivityResultHelper{
    ImageView img;
    int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    int REQUEST_CAMERA=2;
    int RESULT_OK=3;
    Context context;

    public ActivityResultHelper(Context _context){
        this.context = _context;
    }

    //@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        String TAG = ImageUtil.class.getSimpleName();

        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

//            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)context.findViewById(R.id.default_image);
//            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            Log.i(TAG, "destination= " + destination);
            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/danielgindi/android-helpers for help. I think this guy has made something like this.